# NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData: incomprehensible archive crash

Tags: ios, nskeyedunarchiver

I have the following problem while unarchiving a file, which contains an xml string.

It crashes at the following line:

```
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unarchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingWithData:data];
```

'data' (27580 bytes) comes from:

```
NSMutableData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

And the crash i got:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver
>   initForReadingWithData:]: incomprehensible archive (0x62, 0x70, 0x6c,
>   0x69, 0x73, 0x74, 0x30, 0x30)'

The file was created that way:

```
NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];

NSData *project = [ProjectToXML convertProject:SelectedProject];

[archiver encodeObject:project forKey:kProjectKey];
[archiver finishEncoding];
```

'convertProject:' does basically create an NSMutableString with the xml content and converts it to NSData that way ('encoding' is utf-8):

```
[xmlString dataUsingEncoding: CFStringConvertEncodingToNSStringEncoding(CFStringConvertIANACharSetNameToEncoding((__bridge CFStringRef)encoding)) allowLossyConversion:NO];
```

Comment: How did you create that file?

Comment: Can you unarchive the data directly after archiving it (i.e. without saving to a file first)?

Comment: Yes! It worked all the time, only with one specific file I got this error.
Maybe the size of the data is too big?

Comment: Perhaps that one file got corrupted then.  If it crashed during write, etc, that could happen.

Comment: No, it couldnt have crashed, because that file was sent via mail after creating.
Any idea how I can unarchive this file anyway?

Comment: If you can't unarchive it that way, then I doubt you can unarchive it at all without analyzing the data with a hex editor.

Comment: I had the same issue with the same error: "[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: incomprehensible archive", and it only crashed on iOS 8. The problem was that when the data was archiving, it was archived even object which was nil. Now I added a check                  if ([self lastLocation] != nil) {
        [[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:[self lastLocation]] writeToFile:LOC_CACHE_PATH atomically:YES];
    }

Comment: @Lily, just to clarify - has this been fixed in iOS 9 and up?